# Facebook PHP SDK - How to keep the member Logged in?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When the member after closing browser or a few hour passed ,my member need to log-in to my website again, but the Facebook account still Logged-in.

I'm using Facebook PHP SDK, the latest version.

How can I do fix this problem without using Javascript SDK?

I just wanna keep the member log-in status as Facebook log-in status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Extending Access Tokens**  since the removal of offline access, facebook offers an extension to the 2 hour tokens given by default.

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/

---

*deprecated*

**offline_access**
Enables your app to perform authorized requests on behalf of the user at any time. By default, most access tokens expire after a short time period to ensure applications only make requests on behalf of the user when the are actively using the application. This permission makes the access token returned by our OAuth endpoint long-lived.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/#publishing

Using offline access should extend that login period.

---

i cannot say how long you users will stay logged in, but in my app at https://apps.facebook.com/anotherfeed i have been logged in for about 4 days now.

---

11.30.2011:11:14am
I was able to successfully logout with Javascript SDK with offline permission, but Failed to logout yet with PHP-SDK.

---

Comment: I cannot log-out from my website if I'm using offline_access
and also not work

Comment: are you using an access_token on your logout link?

Comment: Let me retract the above, With some testing i found out i can no logout through my logout links now either.  with or with out an access_token.  I will investigate further and edit in what i find in the answer above ok, i was however able to logout using Facebook Logout in upper right.  Testing Javascript Next after coffee is done.

Comment: @ShawnECarter Forget the coffee! Theres more important things afoot! What was the answer here? I have the same problem - although i CANNOT find the offline_access token anywhere.  Where is it!!

Comment: facebook has removed offline access, you either get a 2 hour token or you can exchange that for an extended token. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/